# How to italic a text using PdfContentByte in iTextSharp

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, itext

I want to create footer text with italic font style.

Please correct my code and give me a solution.

```
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,   BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);                         
canvas.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);   
PdfGState gStateFooter = new PdfGState();
gStateFooter.FillOpacity = 1f; 
canvas.SetGState(gStateFooter);
canvas.BeginText(); 
canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);                        
canvas.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, '"' + "When printed, this documents are considered uncontrolled" + '"', 300.7f, 60.7f, 0);  
canvas.EndText(); 
cb.EndLayer();
```

Note:

- using iTextSharp 5.5.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you select the standard, *non-italic* variant of Helvetica

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

To select an *italic* variant, use Helvetica-Oblique:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```